# Окончания среднего и женского рода существительрых на -ье множественного числа

Tags: грамматика

Есть правило "окончание существительных среднего и женского рода на -ье" если ударение падает на основу, то окончание -ий. Слово "платье", почему окончание -ьев, а не -ий?

Answer (score 1):

1) Существительные ср. рода **низовье, верховье, платье, устье** в Р.п. мн. числа имеют окончание ЕВ.  http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.17

**Это грамматика.**  Существительные разных родов и склонений  могут иметь всего  **три вида окончаний** в Р.п. мн. числа (**ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ и нулевое**).  Большинство существительных **ср. рода** в форме Р.п. мн. числа имеют **нулевое** окончание (это их основная форма), но есть несколько исключений.

2) **Правило Розенталя — это орфография.** Правило позволяет выбрать нужную форму  ЕЙ или ИЙ, если гласный находится в безударной позиции. При этом предполагается, что граматическая задача уже решена.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=40#pp40

Существительные на неударяемые -ья и -ье имеют в форме родительного падежа множественного числа окончание -ий: шалу́нья — шалуний, запя́стье — запястий, а на ударяемые -ья и -ьё — окончание -ей: скамья́ — скамей, ружьё — ружей. Но: копьё — копий.

(Правильнее было бы сказать. что  существительные оканчиваются на ИЙ, потому что речь идет об основе, а окончание здесь нулевое).

3) **Примечание**

Вообще говоря, при выборе ИЙ/ЕЙ мы имеем **4 различных варианта (грамматических и орфографических):**

**1. ИЙ в основе для существительных на ИЯ, ИЕ:**

***армия – армий, селение – селений, затмение – затмений.***

**2.  ИЙ в основе (беглая гласная И)**

Существительные среднего рода на ЬЕ в форме Р.п. множественного числа оканчиваются на ИЙ, где И – беглая гласная, если в начальной форме ударение падает на основу:

***поместье – поместий, гнездовье – гнездовий, снАдобье – снАдобий.***

**3. ЕЙ в основе (беглая гласная Е)**

Существительные женского и среднего рода на ЬЯ, ЬЁ в форме Р.п. множественного числа оканчиваются на ЕЙ, где Е – беглая гласная, если в начальной форме ударение падает на окончание: ***ружьё – ружей, судья – судей, полынья – полынЕй,***  но: ***копьё – копий*** (исключение).

**4. Окончание ЕЙ**

Существительные разных родов с мягкой основой в форме Р.п. множественного числа могут иметь ненулевое окончание ЕЙ:  ***сакля – саклей, поле – полей, акварели – акварелей, заросли – зарослей.***