# Можно ли считать орфографию наукой и есть ли у нас такая наука?

Tags: терминология

Речь идет о правописании вообще (орфография и пунктуация).

У нас нет учебника по орфографии, есть только правила. **Школьные учебники русского языка — это микс из фонетики, грамматики и орфографии.** Может быть поэтому за 11 лет   люди так и не могут научиться грамотно писать.

**Вот, к примеру, два недавних вопроса.**

1) **Почему мы пишем платье — платьев,** если по Розенталю слово должно оканчиваться на ИЙ?  [Окончания среднего и женского рода существительрых на -ье множественного числа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443118/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Но у Розенталя правило **орфографическое**. Если поставить здесь точку, меня не поймут, надо добавить, что орфография изучает **парные фонетические варианты** (например, выбор ЕЙ/ИЙ, звучащих одинаково). Но этот термин  многим незнаком, поэтому надо его определить и т.д.

И всё это, как мне кажется, должно быть в школьных учебниках, об этом простыми словами надо рассказывать  маленьким детям с 1-го класса.

2) **Вопрос с другого сайта.** Что такое препинание? Почему некоторые знаки называются знаками препинания?

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3012022-chto-takoe-prepinanie-pochemu-nekotorye-znaki-nazyvajutsja-znakami-prepinanija.html

Вот интересно, в каком возрасте человек начинает задавать себе такие вопросы. Можно почитать ответы: "Если речь у вас **развита**, вы заметите, что в тех местах, где должны быть запятые, вы делаете паузу... "

Название действительно напрямую связано с паузами (остановкой, препятствием в речи). **А что современная наука пунктуация об этом думает?** Да, эта связь в правилах не отрицается, да вот проявляется она не всегда.  И еще много вопросов без ответов. К примеру, логическое ударение — это что? А перечислительную интонацию кто-нибудь определяет? О других же видах интонации и речи нет.

**Разумеется, да, всё это изучается, определяется, но только к практической пунктуации отношения не имеет.** Там же есть только бесконечные правила, привязанные к конкретным ситуациям, но нет их обоснования. Выучить правила сложно, а понять невозможно вовсе — учебника-то нет.

И интересно высказывание насчет речи, потому что **развитая речь** — это не только паузы, но еще и правильное движение тона и даже правильный произносительный темп. **А кто нашим школьникам эту речь поставит и сделает её "развитой"?** Нет для этого ни учебников, ни учителей.

3) **Наука начинается с определений и аксиом, образец — геометрия Евклида.** А что у нас? У нас есть вполне современные "Общие сведения о русском письме".

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=2#pp2

Русское письмо — **звуко-буквенное**: основные его единицы — буквы соотносятся с фонетическими (звуковыми) единицами языка. (Ну да, письмо звуковое, а не слоговое).

Правила, определяющие **общепринятую** запись слов, называются правилами орфографии. (А что, есть еще не общепринятая запись?).

...буквенная передача звукового состава слов определяется **двумя типами правил:** общими правилами употребления букв (их называют также правилами графики) и правилами написания значимых частей слова.

Не очень понятно, тогда я переведу. У нас есть: (1) Правила обозначения мягких звуков и звука Й. Это фактически соответствие между 33 буквами и 42 звуками. (2) Правила написания **морфем (не слов!)**. Почему так? Слишком много вопросов задаете.

Знаки препинания...не участвуют в оформлении слова, а расчленяют письменный текст, выделяют **синтаксические единицы.** (Только  грамматический принцип пунктуации, о семантическом и интонационном забыли).

И вопрос: **Можно ли считать современное описание орфографии и пунктуации наукой?**

**Русское правописание существует само по себе как как некий феномен** (имеющий высокий уровень  и неограниченные возможности для дальнейшего развития и обновления, к нему нет вопросов!), но вот **его грамотного описания и анализа нет. Почему?**

Comment: Скажите уже что-нибудь кто-нибудь)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы классифицировал *орфографию* как **средство стандартизации** записи речи, опирающееся на *уже исследованные* закономерности устройства и развития языка. Эти закономерности могут быть предметом исследования науки, орфография же использует готовые результаты и потому наукой **не является**.

Определение от академика Я. К. Грота (1885г.):

> Правописанием (орфографией) называется **общепринятый на практике и
>   узаконенный теорией способ** начертания слов как отдельно, так и во
>   взаимной их связи. Поэтому к правописанию относятся троякие правила:
>
> 1) об употреблении той или другой буквы;
>
> 2) о соединении двух слов в
>   одно и о переносе частей слова из строки в строку;
>
> 3) об употреблении
>   знаков препинания и других облегчающих правильное чтение знаков.

Полностью 11-е издание его труда "Русское правописание":

http://imwerden.de/pdf/grot_russkoe_pravopisanie_1894.pdf

Частные вопросы:

1) О платьях. Это вопрос о правилах и исключениях. Закономерности языка не всегда укладываются в компактные правила. Правила словообразования полезны как ориентир, но нельзя подогнать под них то, что противоречит им на глубинных основаниях (напр. внешняя по отношению данному к правилу закономерность, традиция).

2) О препинаниях. Изначально (и это соответствует смыслу слова) соотв. знаки предназначались для передачи интонации, прежде всего для расстановки пауз. Но развитие пунктуации пошло (в интересах обучения) по пути разделения на грамматические конструкции, и во многих случаях современная русская пунктуация *противоречит* требуемой *интонации* (обычно знаки оказываются "лишними", как после союза "и"; для сравнения - в английском запятые используются гораздо реже), она стала системой условностей.

Answer (score 0):

КОММЕНТАРИЙ НА [ПОЛУЧЕННЫЙ ОТВЕТ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/443139/178412) @Alex_ander

**1) ОРФОГРАФИЯ.** **Рассмотрим, к примеру, растительный мир.** Это **ЯВЛЕНИЕ**, которое существует само по себе. Люди много лет изучали растения, знакомились с их свойствами , и это был **описательный период** науки. Но вот пришел Карл Линней  и создал **единую систему классификации** растительного  мира, в которой были «обобщены и упорядочены знания всего предыдущего периода развития биологической науки".  Такой же подвиг совершил  Менделеев. Усилиями этих ученых  разрозненные знания сводились в систему — **так рождалась наука в ее настоящем понимании.**

**Язык — это тоже саморазвивающееся явление**, люди могут влиять на него, но не управлять им. Они могут изучать, собирать материал, описывать языковую систему. Лингвистика — это наука **о явлении**, которое называется языком. На каком-то этапе появляется потребность в записи устной речи, а потом — в ЕДИНООБРАЗНОЙ её записи. Но при этом ищутся оптимальные возможности для передачи  смысла звучащего слова. Отвергается фонетическое письмо и утверждается письмо фонематическое (смысловое).

**За 300 лет своего развития русское правописание превратилось в устойчивую систему, письменная речь тоже стала ЯВЛЕНИЕМ, которое НАДО ИЗУЧАТЬ.**  Мы пользуемся системой письма,  но освоить в совершенстве ее не можем. Система уже существовала на практике, а принципы ее (морфологический, фонематический, семантический, интонационный, грамматический) только начали изучаться.  **Это и есть описательный период,** а настоящая наука будет создана позже, **когда все эти знания сведет в единую систему какой-нибудь лингвистический гений**.

К сожалению, у нас нет общего понимания того, что **система русского письма  базируется на ГРАММАТИКЕ,** то есть является **частью языка,  а не  УСЛОВНЫМ  И ОБЩЕПРИНЯТЫМ СОГЛАШЕНИЕМ.** Я знаю, что многие так считают, но это ошибка. Когда так будут СЧИТАТЬ ВСЕ, то живая система будет постепенно **разрушаться, упрощаться и  сводиться к примитивному состоянию,** чтобы все пользователи стали  наконец  «грамотными».

**2) ПУНКТУАЦИЯ.** Сейчас наша пунктуация позволяет **услышать  все тональные переходы, все оттенки устной речи.**  Потому что если приглядеться, то в предложении можно увидеть запятые. Их ставят те, кто еще **не разучился это делать.**

Comment: >услышать все тональные переходы, все оттенки устной речи
Это верно только для киборгов.

Comment: Если считать, что " развитие пунктуации пошло (в интересах обучения) по пути разделения на грамматические конструкции", то  (опять же в интересах  обучения плохо обучаемых) все остальные пользователи вообще ничего не услышат. Вот зачем в сложном предложении с одним придаточным ставить запятую? Там разделителем является союз. А кто и зачем придумал объединять однородные придаточные  и не ставить запятую перед союзом И. Что нам дает это правило? А если ничего не дает, то зачем  оно?

Comment: Если пунктуация - это только условность, то половину правил нужно отменить или упростить. Давайте будем ставить только точки, ну и  запятые иногда, если союзов нет.